# Page snapping middle-out / right-to-left on load

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am working on a website and can't seem to get rid of "page snapping" a page loads.  I originally created this app with node.js, and converted it to static pages using the yeoman [gulp webapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp).

To illustrate, I've created a gif:

[image: page jumping]

The full site is available on my [github](https://github.com/pcooney10/editor-portfolio/tree/gh-pages), it's essentally some semantic-ui components with my own css. To prvent the page from snapping, I added the following styles to the body:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

I thought this would prevent the page from snapping, but I think I am missing something.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the issue. It is because of your content not getting generated at the first and getting the width because of the content. To fix that, give a `min-width`:

```css
.column.features .ui.compact.segment {
  min-width: 450px;
}
```

I could see that adding this CSS fixes it. May be you can remove it after your content is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Hi Praveen - it seems to work well for the middle out snapping, but now it is snapping from right to left (like on the Experience page) @PraveenKumar

Comment: @pingo Lemme check. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Not exactly sure what needs to be done. But it's still snapping from right ot left: http://imgur.com/bGhuiIF

Comment: Also would `min-width:450px` mess up display on mobile devices?

Comment: @pingo Yes, you are right. But the new effect looks cool. LoL. Lemme check again for a suitable solution. And wait, don't give `min-width`. Let's do something with animation! `:P`

Comment: yo @PraveenKumar try removing the `.center.aligned.column` div all together.... problem solved... lol

Comment: @pingo Yay!!! That's good. Did it took sooo long for us to get this working? LoL.

Comment: Yea i know SO long.. literally had to remove one line too lol... new live version is at juliericevuto.com

Comment: @pingo awesome... I'll have a look at it.

Comment: yup yup thank you.. may want to edit your answer too, the original version is still live here: http://pcooney10.github.io/editor-portfolio/.  I am not sure what css property was causing the unwanted effect, but it was on this container: `<div class="center aligned column"'>...</div>`